How do I get the directories of the IP-cores of the Vivado project?
There is a get_ips function, it returns a list of names of all IP-cores of the project. Is there any way to get the directories where the files of these IP-cores are located by some function?

Have you tried report_property -all on one of those IP objects yet? If it remembers what file it came from, that is likely to be described as a property... or at least that's how I'd do it. (I've never used Vivado...)
